# Creating two or more APIs using Cloud Endpoints in Android Studio

Tags: android, api, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am trying to create two APIs using Cloud Endpoints module in Android Studio but when I use all the required annotations and run my local development server it does not create any new API but just one API. Is there another method to create more than one API. Please help me create more than one API for the same backend module. 
[image: This is the only API that endpoint is generating]

This is my second API

```
@Api(name = "myApi2", version = "v1")
public class LoginEndpoint
{
       @ApiMethod(name = "storeData")
public  MyBean storeData(@Named("eid")String eid, @Named("uname")String uname, @Named("password")String pass)


{
    MyBean bean = new MyBean();
    bean.dataStored = true;
    DatastoreService datastore =    DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    Transaction txn = datastore.beginTransaction();

    try{

        Key employeeKey = KeyFactory.createKey("Users", uname);
        Entity user = new Entity(employeeKey);
        user.setProperty("Username", uname);
        user.setProperty("Email id", eid);
        user.setProperty("Password", pass);
        datastore.put(user);
        txn.commit();

    }finally {
        if (txn.isActive())
        {
            txn.rollback();
            bean.dataStored = false;
        }
    }

    return bean;
}     
}
```

This is my first API

```
/**
 * An endpoint class we are exposing
 */
@Api(name = "myApi", version = "v1")
public class MyEndpoint
{


    /**
      * A simple endpoint method that takes a name and says Hi back
     */
    @ApiMethod(name = "sayHi")
    public MyBean sayHi(@Named("name") String name) {
    MyBean respon = new MyBean();
    respon.setData("Hi," + name);

    DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    Transaction txn = datastore.beginTransaction();
    try {
        Key employeeKey = KeyFactory.createKey("Employee", "Joe");
        Entity employee = new Entity(employeeKey);
        employee.setProperty("vacationDays", 10);

        datastore.put(employee);

        txn.commit();
    } finally {
        if (txn.isActive()) {
            txn.rollback();
        }
    }

    return respon;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to achieve is a Multiclass API. As you can read on the documentation [1]: "Any difference in the @Api properties for classes in a multiclass API result in an "ambiguous" API configuration, which will not work in Endpoints."

So yo could use annotation inheritance to split you API's with Java inheritance or with @ApiReference inheritance. Detailed info is provided on [1].

Another alternative is to use different backend versions as described here [2].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/multiclass

[2] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/test_deploy#deploying_to_multiple_app_versions

Comment: I tried using both but it didn't work. Any change made in myApi are reflected in the local development server but it doesn't create any new API other than myApi. I want to create second API 'myApi2'. Please help me out.

Comment: What I was explaining was that there is no way of having two APIs on the same project, you simply can't not deply two APIs. Basically, you'll have to create another project and have the "myApi2" API on a new project.

Comment: Thanks! I got a reasonable answer!

Comment: @RishabJaiswal, do you mean my answer or other's answer? If it's the latter please share it otherwhise, please accept my answer.